# How can I make the mean of samples be approximately equal to the mean of actual continuous signal?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing, sampling

Suppose there is signal f(t) that is continuous and periodic. It is known that this f is T-periodic. (but it's not necessarily a single cosine f(t).( I'd like to make the mean of samples be approximately equal to the man of actual continuous f(t).

Is the use of nyquist sampling rate mandatory in such a case? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If $F(\omega)$ is the signal's FT, then $F(0)$ is the mean. Any spectral content at multiples of the sampling frequency will be indistinguishable from a constant value (i.e., $\omega=0$), so the sampling rate requirement in this situation is more relaxed than Nyquist. As long as $F(\omega) = 0 \,\, \forall \,\, \vert \omega \vert \geq f_s$, then the DC value of the DFT will be the same as that of the continuous time FT.